# Верно ли записано уравнение на C#

Tags: c#

Уравнение такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Никак не могу записать формулу.
Верно ли у меня записано?

```
Double x = 14.26, y = -1.22, z = 3.5 * Math.Pow(10.0, -2), t;
t = (2*Math.Cos(x-Math.PI/6))/(0.5+Math.Pow(Math.Sin(y), 2)) * ((1 + Math.Pow(z, 2)) / (3-Math.Pow(z, 2)/5));
```

Потому что результат совершенно не совпадает с вышеприведенным требуемым результатом, а именно
 t = 0,188451240697501, а мне нужно, чтобы t выводил 0,564849.

Comment: По-моему там знак умножения вместо переменной "x". И имеется в виду 10 в минус второй степени, а не 10 минус два, как у вас.:)

Comment: Это и не уравнение вовсе, а просто пример

Comment: Вы приняли ответ, и изменили вопрос - нехорошо. Теперь текущие ответы не отвечают на текущий вопрос, и кроме вас никому другому пользу вопрос не принесёт.

Comment: Перепроверьте скобки в новом уравнении. вы сбились в правой части.

Comment: инициализировать переменные со степенью числа 10 всё-таки не имеет смысл через `Math.Pow`. Для этого есть литерал, представленный в ответе @PetSerAl

Comment: @4per, хотел я удалить вопрос. Но не смог, поэтому и запросил модератора, чтобы он удалил сей вопрос.

Comment: @GhostBasenji Пожалуйста учитывайте, что участники общества тратят свое время, чтобы помочь Вам абсолютно бесплатно и с Вашей стороны было как минимум невежливо изменять вопрос после того как Вы получили ответ. Поэтому после получения ответа если у Вас возник новый вопрос, нужно задавать новый **отдельный** вопрос, а не изменять вопрос. Вопрос удалить не можете, т.к. уже есть ответы на него.

Comment: @Alex я ничего не давал

Comment: @4per уже понял, я думал Вы ответ написали

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, по-моему, должно быть `z = 3.5*Math.Pow(10.0, -2)`.

Answer (score 5):

Это не формула, а просто константа:

```
z = 3.5e-2;
```